# GitHub Action Set $GITHUB_ENV Not Saving

Tags: github, github-actions

Per the documentation found [here](https://docs.github.com/en/github-ae@latest/actions/using-workflows/workflow-commands-for-github-actions#setting-an-environment-variable), I have tried setting a GitHub Action environment variable but noticed that the env variables don't seem to save. Has this been deprecated or is the documentation / my implementation just incorrect?

```
- name: Get Gradle VersionName
  working-directory : ${{ github.workspace }}/app
  run : |
    echo "Get Gradle VersionName"
    echo "action_state=yellow" >> $GITHUB_ENV
    echo "${{ env.action_state }}"
    grep 'versionName' build.gradle | awk '{print $2}'
```

[image]

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This behaviour is expected since *"the step that creates or updates the environment variable does not have access to the new value, but all subsequent steps in a job will have access."* ([documentation](https://docs.github.com/en/github-ae@latest/actions/using-workflows/workflow-commands-for-github-actions#setting-an-environment-variable))

To illustrate, consider the following definition of steps:

```
steps:
   - name: Step 1
     run: |
        echo "action_state=yellow" >> $GITHUB_ENV
        echo "State is: '${{ env.action_state }}'" # No output since same step
   - name: Step 2
     run: |
        echo "State is: '${{ env.action_state }}'" # Output works
```

Which results in this output:

[image: result]

Answer (score 2):

Github Actions new requires and explicit "runs-on".  The above example will run on ubuntu-latest bash.

Powershell and Windows Command examples on windows-latest follow:

```
on: [push, pull_request]

# GitHub Action Set $GITHUB_ENV Not Saving
# 2022
# https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71333335/github-action-set-github-env-not-saving

# based on
# Example of writing an environment variable to GITHUB_ENV
# https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-commands-for-github-actions#setting-an-environment-variable

jobs:

  build_ubuntu_latest:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
    - name: Set the value
      id: step_one
      shell: bash
      run: |
        # bash
        echo "action_state=yellow" >> $GITHUB_ENV
        echo "State is: '${{ env.action_state }}'" # No output since same step

    - name: Use the value
      id: step_two
      shell: bash
      run: |
        # bash
        echo "Action State is: '${{ env.action_state }}'" # Output works

  build_windows_latest:
    runs-on: windows-latest

    steps:
    - name: Set the value1
      id: step_one1
      run: |
        # powershell
        Add-Content -Path ${env:GITHUB_ENV} -Value "sleep_state1=red"
        # No output since same step
        echo "Sleep State 1 is ${{ env.sleep_state1 }}" 

    - name: Set the value2
      id: step_one2
      shell: cmd
      run: |
        rem windows command
        printf "sleep_state2=purple" >> %GITHUB_ENV%
        rem No output since same step
        printf "Sleep State 2 is ${{ env.sleep_state2 }}"

    - name: Use the value again 1
      id: step_two1
      run: |
        # powershell
        echo "Sleep State 1 is ${{ env.sleep_state1 }}" # Output works
        echo "Sleep State 2 is ${{ env.sleep_state2 }}" # Output works

    - name: Use the value again 2
      id: step_two2
      shell: cmd
      run: |
        rem windows command
        rem Output works
        printf "Sleep State 1 is ${{ env.sleep_state1 }}\n"
        rem Output works
        printf "Sleep State 2 is ${{ env.sleep_state2 }}\n"
```